# PHP : Remove words less than 3 characters in unicode text

Tags: regex, unicode, character

I use these regex to remove words less than 3 characters :

```
$str = preg_replace("!\\b\\w{1,3}\\b!", "", $str);
```

and

```
$rdu = "/\b[^\b]{1,2}\b/";
$str = preg_replace($rdu , " ", " " . $str . " ");
```

but in unicode text return me :

```
� �� �� �������� ��� �� � �� �� �������� ��� �� 
....
```

is there any way with or without regex to remove words less than 3 characters in unicode text?

THXA

Answer (score 4):

Use the [*u* modifier for UTF-8 support](http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers):

```
/\b\w{1,2}\b/u
```

Comment: I use U , return text correctly but words less than 3 characters still there.

Answer (score 0):

```
function RemoveLess($String,$Char=2)
{

    $StringArray=explode (" ",$String);

    foreach ($StringArray as &$Word) 
    {
        if (mb_strlen($Word,"UTF-8")>$Char)
        {
            $Str.=$Word." ";
        }
    }

    return trim($Str);

}


$text="any text here - لا اله إلا الله محمد رسول الله";

echo RemoveLess($text);
```

Comment: Hi Khaled, thanks for your answer. Code only answers are discouraged here however; do you think you could edit your answer to explain why this solves the OP's problem?